# Rails3 xhr response served as text/html instead of text/javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, xmlhttprequest

I just upgraded an application from Rails 2.3 to Rails 3.0. This application make extensive use of Ajax.

Since the upgrade, each

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

Responds with a content type of `text/html` instead of `text/javascript` (as viewed in Firebug). The XHR request specifies `Accept="text/javascript"`. The result is that Prototype refuse to eval the response, so no more magic on my pages…

For precision, I decided to include the legacy RailsPrototypeHelpers, the full UJS app will be the next application.

For information, I tried to put the js in js.rjs files: content-type is still 'text/html'
I tried to inline js and force with `render :update, :content_type => 'text/javascript'`: no luck, still answer with 'text/html' content_type.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Same happening here, but weirder. Chrome and Safari are ok. On Firefox, however, content type is set to `text/javascript` on first post request, but `text/html` on the second one, which gives me a 406. Using Rails 3.2.3

Comment: This issue still exists although it doesn't seem to be affecting everyone: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14173.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having a similar problem. I found that I could get it to return `text/javascript` if I added this:

```
headers["Content-Type"] = "text/javascript; charset=utf-8"
render :update do |page|
    ...
end
```

or

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js {headers["Content-Type"] = "text/javascript; charset=utf-8"}
end
```